# Inductive Step For a Summation mathematical induction

Tags: induction

I have a bit of trouble with how I should go about showing the inductive step for my induction problem. I know the general idea is to show that it can work for all numbers based on the base case but I'm still stuck on how to show it.

$\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} \leq \frac{n}{2}$ for n $\geq$ 2

I know we have to plug in k+1 instead of n and show that it is also equal to k by using algebra. I'm just stuck on how to show it. I guess the i is the part that confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Compare

$$\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}\frac{1}{i} \leq \frac{k+1}{2}$$

to $$\sum_{i=2}^k\frac{1}{i} \leq \frac{k}{2}.$$

On the left-hand sides, the difference is $\dfrac1{k+1}$, and on the right-hand sides, it is $\dfrac12$.

Can you conclude ?